# Preparing a Matrix in C++ for Matlab

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, matrix

I have a sparse matrix P of dimension dim*dim given as a pointer through

```
double* P

/* create the output matrix */
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(dim,dim,mxREAL);

/* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix*/
P = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
```

I do this in a mex file since I need a lot of for-loops to fill P and c++ is much faster then matlab for that.

For the moment, dim=22500 and it takes about 2 seconds for c++ to fill P (with matlab this task took 50 seconds), and about 100 seconds to normalize the matrix in matlab and again 100 Seconds to erase all zero colums in matlab. I do this with the following code in matlab:

```
for i=1:size(P,1)
    if sum(P(i,:)) > 0
        sum(P(i,:))
        P(i,:)=(1/sum(P(i,:))).*P(i,:);
    end
end

% clear empty rows and colunms
P(~any(P,2),:)=[];
P(:,~any(P))=[];
```

My question is now: Can I do this in c++ aswell? I tried to normalize P in c++ in the following way:

```
int i;
int j;
int sum;
int get_idx(int x, int y, int rows) {
   return x +y * rows;   
}
/* NORMALIZE */
for(i = 0; i <dim; i++)  {
    sum=0;
    for(j=0; j<dim;j++) {   
        sum = sum + P[get_idx(i,j,dim)];
    }
    if(sum > 0) {
         for(j=0; j<dim;j++) {   
           P[get_idx(i,j,p_rows)]=P[get_idx(i,j,dim)]*(1/sum);
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason this code does not seem to change P, and also this takes about 85 seconds in c++. Is there a faster way that also works? Also, is it possible to clear empty rows and columns?

Comment: For your c++ code: `sum` should be a double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why C++?

Clear the empty rows/columns before normalization - you don't need to normalize empty entries.

Vectorize the normalization:

```
s = sum(P, 2);
valid = s > 0;
P( valid,: ) = bsxfun(@rdivide, P(valid,:), s(valid) );
```

Ta-da!

[bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) is so much fun!

---

**Update:** Regarding the reduction of rows/columns.
After a short investigation I think there is a ~x3 speed factor to gain:

Consider these three options:

1. `P( ~any(P,2), :) = []; P( :, ~any(P,1) ) = [];`
2. `P( :, ~any(P,1) ) = []; P( ~any(P,2), :) = [];`
3. `P = P( any(P,2), any(P,1) );`

Test these three alternatives and you'll see that the third one is ~x3 faster, while the first is slight (but consistently) slower than the second.

Why?
If you recall, Matlab stores matices in memory in a column-first fashion therefore eliminating columns before rows saves some copying and re-allocation of memory.

Yet, the first and second alternatives copy and reallocate memory **twice**: once for rows and once for columns, while the third alternative messes with the memory only once!

Comment: Wow! I used that instand of my for-loop to normalize it (actually I used bsxfun(@rdivide, P(valid,__:__), s(valid) );) and it is much faster! Instead of 100 seconds to normalize it, it takes now just 2 seconds. Thank you.

Still, the part where I get rid of all zero-entrys is still slowing down everything. Do you have a advice how I can speed that up? Should I use matlab or c++ do to that?

Comment: @Adam: reducing the size of a matrix is a costly operation - it requires re-allocation of memory and copy of many elements to make the resulting matrix fit in a single chunk in memory. use `profile` to examine this part of code.

Comment: @Adam - you can see my update regarding the removing of rows/columns from `P`

Comment: Thank you very much. But even 3x faster is still 33 seconds. I have rewritten my whole code to avoid writing a matrix with zero-rows in it. Now everythings just takes about 1 sec, I am allright with that. THANK YOU SO MUCH :)